# How to say "I am confused"?

Tags: translation, word-requests, idioms

I have found the following examples in http://tatoeba.org/jpn/

> 頭{あたま}が混乱{こんらん}している。I'm confused.
>
> 本当{ほんとう}に参{まい}りましたね。I'm really confused.

Are these examples a natural way to deliver the idea of being confused?

Comment: Onomatopoeia: あわわわわ…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are so many ways to say "I am confused." that you might not get a very good answer unless you explain what situation/context you have in mind.

「頭が混乱している。」 is "good" in the sense that it could not really mean anything other than "I am confused."  It could sound a little stiff if said in a casual situation as 「混乱」 is a bit of a big word for a light kind of confusion.

「本当に参りましたね。」 would be a hit-or-miss kind of expression in that it can mean many different things.  "Troubled" or "beat" would be the most common meaning of 「参った」, not "confused".

The "real" native-level, non-textbook expressions for "I am confused." that do not use big Sino-loanwords would include:

・訳{わけ}が分{わ}からない

・まごついてしまう

・困{こま}ってしまう

・うろたえてしまう

Then again, you might have a situation in mind where the use of a big word is completely appropriate.

Comment: Can you say まごついている instead of まごついてしまう?

Answer (score 1):

混乱 is the proper word to express confusion.
So your first sentence is good.
There could be a few other ways to express confusion but I am not sure I would consider the second sentence one of them unless used in a very specific way/situation.

参りました or the casual 参った means you have lost/given up etc...
For example, I suppose you could use it to your friend after a very complicated math class to express the fact that you didn't understand anything. As in you have been defeated by your teacher or given up understanding what the hell is going on in that class.